# UIAlertView keeps re-appearing after dismissWithClickedButtonIndex included in performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, uialertview

I have a button which I want to implement with password before triggering a segue if the password is correct. it all looks fine up to the moment when you type in wrong password and I have implemented another alertView to tell the user the password is wrong. **When the alert view pops out and dismisses after some delay, it keeps re-appearing and disappearing and nothing else can be done on the screen!**
How to stop the re appearing?
Below is my part of the code that deals with this:

```
- (IBAction)editLeagues:(id)sender {

    [self presentAlertViewForPassword];

}

-(void)presentAlertViewForPassword
{

    _passwordAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Password"
                                                           message:@"Enter Password to edit Leagues"
                                                          delegate:self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [_passwordAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput];
    _passwordField = [_passwordAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    _passwordField.delegate = self;
    _passwordField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    _passwordField.tag = textFieldPassword;
    [_passwordAlert show];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"55555"];

      if ( ![_passwordField.text isEqual:password]) {

          _wrongPassword = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrong Password"
                                                                message:@"You are not authorised to use this feature!"
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [_wrongPassword show];

        [self performSelector:@selector(allertViewDelayedDissmiss:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
    }
    else
    {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addLeague" sender:[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:0]];
    }

}

-(void) allertViewDelayedDissmiss:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    [_wrongPassword dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];

}


- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    NSString *inputText = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    if( [inputText length] >= 4 )
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[_wrongPassword dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];` will call the delegate method `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`

You have two options:

1. don't set a delegate on the wrong password alert
2. check for the correct alert in `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` e.g.

   ```
   - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
   {
       if (alert == _passwordAlert) {
           NSString *password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"55555"];
           // and so on
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Matthias but when I do that the wrong password alert shows for a second and disappears! In this way the user will not be able to see the message.My intention was to show the user what is wrong that is why I have added the delay method, which works fine, it delays the disappearance of the window but after it goes it comes again and this keeps repeating.

Comment: You can still use the delayed method. Just don't set a delegate to the wrong password alert or check that you only call the code that checks for the password if alertView == _passwordAlert

Comment: Thanks @Matthias this helped me a lot just a small problem - if I press cancel button on the first alert without typing any password it pops the wrong password alert :) but i will fix that:)

Comment: simply wrap the password checking code in `if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) { /***/ }`

Answer (score 0):

Issue is causing because when you dismiss the wrong password alert it'll also call the `didDismissWithButtonIndex` delegate method.

**Solution 1**

Set the `delegate` of wrong password alert to `nil`.

```
wrongPassword = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrong Password"
                                                                message:@"You are not authorised to use this feature!"
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

**Solution 2**

Add a tag to your alertView. And change your methods like:

```
-(void)presentAlertViewForPassword
 {
       _passwordAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Password"
                                                       message:@"Enter Password to edit Leagues"
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                             otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
       [_passwordAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput];
       passwordAlert.tag = 7;
       _passwordField = [_passwordAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
       _passwordField.delegate = self;
       _passwordField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
       _passwordField.tag = textFieldPassword;
       [_passwordAlert show];
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView.tag == 7)
    {
       NSString *password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"55555"];
       if ( ![_passwordField.text isEqual:password])
       {
          _wrongPassword = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrong Password"
                                                                message:@"You are not authorised to use this feature!"
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [_wrongPassword show];

        [self performSelector:@selector(allertViewDelayedDissmiss:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
      }
      else
      {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addLeague" sender:[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:0]];
      }
   }
}
```